# How to read and print an Array List in a list?

Tags: c#

I having trouble printing an ArrayList correctly. While debugging I can see that it reads it correctly, but in richTextBox1(finalResults) it prints it as System.Collections.ArrayList

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace Laboratorinis_P3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Museum> firstList;
        List<Museum> newList;
        List<Museum> twoList;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void formListBySelectedCityToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string city = Convert.ToString(Cities.SelectedItem);
            LinqForming(city);
           
        }
        private void findTwoMuseumsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
        private void readFileAndPrintItToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Pasirinkite duomenų failą";
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                firstList = ReadFile(path,firstList);
                PrintList(firstList);
                AddCitiesToComboBox(firstList);
            }
 
        }
       
        static List<Museum> ReadFile(string fv,List<Museum> firstList)
        {
            ArrayList days = new ArrayList();
            firstList = new List<Museum>();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fv))
            {

                string line;
                
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    string[] parts = line.Split(";");
                    string name = parts[0];
                    string city = parts[1];
                    string type = parts[2];
                    string[] day = parts[3].Trim().Split(new[] {' '});
                    days.Clear();
                    foreach (string lines in day)
                    {
                        int dayss = int.Parse(lines);
                        days.Add(dayss);
                    }

                    double adult = double.Parse(parts[4]);
                    double kid = double.Parse(parts[5]);
                    string hasguide = parts[6];
                    Museums museum = new Museums(name, city, type, days, adult, kid, hasguide);
                    firstList.Add(museum);

                }
            }
            return firstList;
        }
        private void LinqForming(string city)
        {
            newList = firstList                     
                      .Where(x => x.City == city)
                      .ToList();
        }
       
        private void AddCitiesToComboBox(List<Museum> list)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!Cities.Items.Contains(list[i].City))
                {
                    Cities.Items.Add(list[i].City);
                }
            }
        }
        private void PrintList(List<Museum> museum)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < museum.Count; i++)
            {
                finalResults.Text += museum[i].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Laboratorinis_P3
{
    class Museum
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string MuseumTypes { get; set; }

        public ArrayList Days { get; set; }
        public double PriceForAdult { get; set; }
        public double PriceForKid { get; set; }
        public string HasGuide { get; set; }

        public Museum()
        {

        }

        public Museum(string name, string city, string type, ArrayList days,
                      double adult, double kid, string hasguide)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.City = city;
            this.MuseumTypes = type;
            this.Days = days;
            this.PriceForAdult = adult;
            this.PriceForKid = kid;
            this.HasGuide = hasguide;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string eilute;
            eilute = string.Format
                ("| {0,5}|{1,13}|{2,10} |{3,9}|{4,12}|{5,13}|{6,10} |",Name,City,MuseumTypes,
                 Days,PriceForAdult,PriceForKid,HasGuide);
                           
            return eilute;
        }
    }
}
```

Data file example

```
Gato;Vilnius;Elektros; 1 2 3 ;8.5;4.5;turi
Miau;Vilnius;Gyvunai; 1 2 ;11.5;2.5;neturi
AuAu;Siauliai;Biologija; 1 2 3;5.0;4.75;turi
GuGa;Panevezys;Menas; 1 2 3;12.15;1.78;turi
```

I tried everything that I could think up with to print it as it should but it does not seem to work.
To add some explanation: the numbers are equal to days, which I am trying to print

Comment: "the numbers are equal to days, which I am trying to print" Can you show an example OUTPUT LINE for what you want generated?  You can override `ToString()` for your "Museum" class to generate that. Then you can use something like `String.Join()` to generate your output quickly.

Comment: For example, the output line should be Gato;Vilnius;Elektros; 1 2 3 ;8.5;4.5;turi but instead it is Gato;Vilnius;Elektros;System.Collections.ArrayList;8.5;4.5;turi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `String.Join()` to put your days together, then insert that into your output string:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string eilute;
    string strDays = String.Join(",", Days.ToArray());
    eilute = string.Format
        ("| {0,5}|{1,13}|{2,10} |{3,9}|{4,12}|{5,13}|{6,10} |", Name, City, MuseumTypes,
         strDays, PriceForAdult, PriceForKid, HasGuide);

    return eilute;
}
```

Comment: This only prints the last "day" elements for them all, they are different from each other, if we took my data example, it prints 1 2 3 for all of them. It replaces the " 1 2" with "1 2 3".

Comment: That's a BUG in your `ReadFile()` method, not a problem from `ToString()`.  In `ReadFile()`,  you're re-using the same ArrayList for each line.  Move `ArrayList days = new ArrayList();` to INSIDE the while loop and you'll see better results.

Answer (score 0):

The `Days` field type is `ArrayList` and that is why you are getting

> ;System.Collections.ArrayList;

change your code to:

```
eilute = string.Format
            ("| {0,5}|{1,13}|{2,10} |{3,9}|{4,12}|{5,13}|{6,10} |",Name,City,MuseumTypes,
             String.Join(" ", Days.ToArray().Select(s => s.ToString())),PriceForAdult,PriceForKid,HasGuide);
```

Comment: This only prints the last outputs line for all days, check data example, if it's this: Gato;Vilnius;Elektros; 1 2 3 ;8.5;4.5;turi \n
Miau;Vilnius;Gyvunai; 1 2 ;11.5;2.5;neturi \n
AuAu;Siauliai;Biologija; 1 2 3;5.0;4.75;turi \n
GuGa;Panevezys;Menas; 1 2 3;12.15;1.78;turi \n                                                                                    It should print on first line: 1 2 3, second - 1 2; third - 1 2 3; fourth - 1 2 3, instead this prints  1 2 3 for all of the "days" ArrayList, even if they're different

Comment: As Idle_Mind said you have a problem inside your loop.